# QGIS csv load moving data across to first empty column

Tags: qgis, csv

I am finding when loading csv's that if there is an empty field(s) then the data is moved from the next occupied field. For example:

[image]

No matter what I have tried the data gets shunted.  Even when create a new file from scratch. I have not seen this behaviour in 5 years of QGIS use? This happens when using the standard csv file format import too.  Just using the custom to show the preview. QGIS 3.28.2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your csv with sample data? Maybe delimiters for empty fields are missing?

Comment: I could fill up all the empty spaces with 0 or N/A and it should prevent your data from moving.

Comment: @Babel - sorry for the delay in response. I can't see how to add an attachment? in notepad++ the commas are definitely there.

Comment: @MKR - thanks but not really a long term sustainable solution

Comment: Expend the "Record and Fields Options" and made sure that the "Discard empty fields" is unckecked

Comment: Thank you @J.R.  I have no idea how that became checked but it was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

As per J.R.'s suggestion, Expand the "Record and Fields Options" and made sure that the "Discard empty fields" is unckecked